Incorrect Email Displayed in Power BI After Azure AD User Email Change
I have an issue with Azure AD user email changes not reflecting correctly in Power BI.
Scenario:
Original email: abc.def@domain.com
Email changed to: abc.xyz@domain.com
Problem:
After the email change, searching for the user in Power BI shows the correct new email.
However, the manage permissions and direct access sections display the old email (abc.def@domain.com).
The Power BI Admin REST API also returns the old email.when we try to getReportUserAsAdmin, it returns the wrong identifier for the user.
This issue is not present in PowerApps or Power Automate, where the email change is correctly reflected.
Questions:
Why is Power BI showing the old email, is it related to something that is not in sync with Azure AD ?
How can I fix this to show the updated email in Power BI?
Any help would be appreciated.

Check the Microsoft Entra ID for duplicate attributes using the Office 365 portal or the Azure Active Directory module for Windows PowerShell. If duplicate attributes are found, they can be resolved by changing the email address so that it's unique.

thanks for reply, there are no duplicates found. Issue is with powerbi service only where it is not showing the updated email address for the user. its showing the older one only even after clearing cache removing the access and regranting etc.. when we search for users in people picker for granting access in power bi, there it shows correct updated email id of the user's but when that user is added to report or workspace it shows the old id.
